# How to apply the one ripple drawable for multiple buttons dynamically in Java?

Tags: java, android, optimization, android-drawable, android-button

I want to apply the same ripple drawable properly on multiple buttons. But it's not happening because, the ripple effect is only getting applied on the last button. I have also used gradient drawable inside the ripple drawable. That works fine on every button. It just the ripple effect is not getting applied on any button except the last button. It is also not working on api level 8. I know that this method doesn't work on apis before api level 21. But I haven't found any tutorial on dynamic button design.

I'm doing everything inside the on-create event. I can't write the codes outside of the on-create event and also can't use any XML for this particular situation I'm in.

Here's the output:

[image]

Here's the code:

```
android.graphics.drawable.GradientDrawable gd_btone = new android.graphics.drawable.GradientDrawable();

gd_btone.setCornerRadius(4);
gd_btone.setStroke(2, Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
gd_btone.setColor(Color.parseColor("#232323"));

android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable ripdr = new android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable(new android.content.res.ColorStateList(new int[][]{new int[]{}}, new int[]{ Color.parseColor("#888888")}), gd_btone, null);

button1.setBackground(ripdr);
button2.setBackground(ripdr);
button3.setBackground(ripdr);
button4.setBackground(ripdr);
```

Also, can anyone help me to make this piece of code back-compatible with api level 8 and how to set margin on this drawable?
I'm not a Android developer so I don't know much about it.

Comment: are you sure your button id is matching to your variable id

Comment: Yes, that's why the gradient drawable is getting applied.

Comment: show me the full code ..lets see if I can help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I see is that the dripple effect is applied to the last button, even when the other buttons are clicked. Because of this, I am thinking that the RippleDrawable class does not support the kind of behavior you are looking for; a single instance can only be bound to one button at a time.

I would suggest simply creating four separate RippleDrawable instances.

Disclaimer: I have not worked with RippleDrawables, but this is purely based on the output you've provided and personal experience with Android development.